# hamburger menu list toggle disappears if click anywhere else on the page

Tags: html, jquery, css

I need your help here, my hamburger menu does work but say when i click on it it display menu list but if supposing i click somewhere else on the webpage the menu disappears. i wish for it to not disappear until clicked on the X.

could someone show me a fix to this?

here is my code

```
<style>
.mobile-nav { z-index: 9999; position: fixed; left: 10px; top: 60px; width: 20px; }
.menu-btn span { display: block; width: 20px; height: 3px; margin: 4px 0; background: #000; z-index: 99; }
.btn1, .btn2, .btn3 { cursor:pointer; width: 25px;  height: 3px;  background-color: #333;  margin: 6px 0;  transition: 0.4s;}
.change .btn1 {  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);  transform: rotate(-55deg) translate(-9px, 2px);}
.change .btn2 {opacity: 0;}
.change .btn3 {  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);  transform: rotate(55deg) translate(-8px, -4px);}
.responsive-menu { box-shadow: 2px 2px; max-height: 0; background-color: #fff; width: 200px; overflow: hidden; transition: all .25s; position: absolute; right: -220px; text-align: left; top: 10px;}
.responsive-menu ul { padding: 20px 0 0 20px; list-style: none; }
.responsive-menu ul li { padding-bottom: 10px; }
.responsive-menu a { text-decoration: none; color: #000;}
.expand {max-height: none; }
</style>

<script>
jQuery(function($){

  $( '.menu-btn' ).click(function(){
    $('.responsive-menu').toggleClass('expand');
  });

  $(document).on("click", function(e){
    if( 
      $(e.target).closest(".responsive-menu").length == 0 &&
      $(".responsive-menu").hasClass("expand") &&
      $(e.target).closest(".menu-btn").length == 0
    ){
      $('.responsive-menu').toggleClass('expand');
    }
  });
});
function myFunction(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("change");
}
</script>

<div class="mobile-nav">
            <div class="menu-btn" id="menu-btn" onclick="myFunction(this)">
                <div class="btn1"></div>
  <div class="btn2"></div>
  <div class="btn3"></div>
            </div>
         
             <div class="responsive-menu">
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="index.php"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> HOME </a></li>
                </ul>
             </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a fixed position pseudo `:before` element on your menu button when expanded to make the whole window a clickable area to close the responsive menu.

Or if you only ever want the menu button to expand/close the responsive menu then just remove the `#mobile-nav.expand #menu-btn::before` css selector from my demo...

I've given this pseudo element a background blue so you can see whats going on in the demo. You can remove this background color so it is invisible or make it semi transparent.

I've tidied up and streamlined your css and jquery by toggling a single `.expand` on the parent mobile nav div. Which can handle all transitions and states of child elements.

Your hamburger menu was not a perfect X either when expanded so I fixed that too and used a button instead of a div.

See fiddles and stack demos below...

**Option 1 - With menu button pseudo before trick**

https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/bvok2nLp/

```js
$(function() {

  $(document).on('click','#menu-btn', function(){
    $('#mobile-nav').toggleClass('expand');
  });

});
```

```css
#mobile-nav {
  z-index: 9999;
  position: fixed;
  left: 10px;
  top: 60px;
  width: 20px;
}

#menu-btn {
  background: transparent;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  z-index: 5;
}

#menu-btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#menu-btn:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
}

#menu-btn SPAN {
  width: 24px;
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 99;
  transition: 0.4s;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 1;
}

#menu-btn SPAN::before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: black;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

#menu-btn SPAN:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#mobile-nav.expand #menu-btn::before {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background: blue;
}

#mobile-nav.expand #menu-btn SPAN:first-child,
#mobile-nav.expand #menu-btn SPAN:last-child {
  transform: translateX(2px);
}

#menu-btn SPAN:first-child::before {
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}

#mobile-nav.expand #menu-btn SPAN:first-child::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#mobile-nav.expand #menu-btn SPAN:nth-child(2)::before {
  opacity: 0;
}

#menu-btn SPAN:last-child::before {
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

#mobile-nav.expand #menu-btn SPAN:last-child::before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#responsive-menu {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px;
  max-height: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .25s;
  position: absolute;
  right: -220px;
  text-align: left;
  top: 10px;
}

#responsive-menu > UL {
  padding: 20px 0 0 20px;
  list-style: none;
}

#responsive-menu > UL > LI {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#responsive-menu A {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

#mobile-nav.expand #responsive-menu {
  max-height: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="mobile-nav">
  <button class="menu-btn" id="menu-btn" onclick="myFunction(this)">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </button>

  <div id="responsive-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.php"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> HOME </a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Option 2 - Without menu button pseudo before trick**

https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/8otup12r/

```js
$(function() {

  $(document).on('click','#menu-btn', function(){
    $('#mobile-nav').toggleClass('expand');
  });

});
```

```css
#mobile-nav {
  z-index: 9999;
  position: fixed;
  left: 10px;
  top: 60px;
  width: 20px;
}

#menu-btn {
  background: transparent;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  z-index: 5;
}

#menu-btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#menu-btn:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
}

#menu-btn SPAN {
  width: 24px;
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 99;
  transition: 0.4s;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 1;
}

#menu-btn SPAN::before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: black;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

#menu-btn SPAN:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

/* remove this so #menu-btn clickable area is not the full window when #mobile-nav is expanded

#mobile-nav.expand #menu-btn::before {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background: blue;
}
*/

#mobile-nav.expand #menu-btn SPAN:first-child,
#mobile-nav.expand #menu-btn SPAN:last-child {
  transform: translateX(2px);
}

#menu-btn SPAN:first-child::before {
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}

#mobile-nav.expand #menu-btn SPAN:first-child::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#mobile-nav.expand #menu-btn SPAN:nth-child(2)::before {
  opacity: 0;
}

#menu-btn SPAN:last-child::before {
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

#mobile-nav.expand #menu-btn SPAN:last-child::before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#responsive-menu {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px;
  max-height: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .25s;
  position: absolute;
  right: -220px;
  text-align: left;
  top: 10px;
}

#responsive-menu > UL {
  padding: 20px 0 0 20px;
  list-style: none;
}

#responsive-menu > UL > LI {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#responsive-menu A {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

#mobile-nav.expand #responsive-menu {
  max-height: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="mobile-nav">
  <button class="menu-btn" id="menu-btn" onclick="myFunction(this)">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </button>

  <div id="responsive-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.php"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> HOME </a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: the second option was exactly what i was looking for. appreciate your help mate.

Comment: @Eveline no worries 